# Get to Schiphol early in the day/sleep at airport?

Tags: airports, amsterdam, sleeping, ams

I will depart from Schiphol on a Sunday at 10:00, and return on some other day at 05:00. What options do I have to travel to/from Schiphol Airport?

- I'd prefer the train, but if I am not mistaken, the first connection from Heerlen will arrive on 09:56, so this is no option.
- I could take the car, parking for two weeks is 100€. But I will have to drive back after a night in the plane, possibly without sleep. So, no option either, I guess.
- Third option is to try to get a hotel room. Best rates I found are 150€ per night. Any tips on that?
- The last night train arrives 04:00. Since I will travel with my sleeping bag could I just take a nap somewhere near/at the airport?

Comment: @pnuts Good tipp. But then, there is this bad review from just a month ago...

Comment: @JoErNanO Even adding train/costs for using your own car, taxi would be way more expensive, Heerlen is at the other end of the country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are trains to Schiphol every hour through the night, it's the Heerlen end of the trip that make it difficult. So you could first go to Utrecht, sleep there and catch a train in the morning. Or go all the way to Leiden or Amsterdam by train on Saturday afternoon and take a train, bus or taxi on Sunday morning. Depending on the type of accommodation/level of comfort, it should be possible to find cheaper ho(s)tel or B&B in those cities than at the airport. You would also have more time to sleep in the morning than if you were to take your own car or a long-distance train during the night.

Answer (score 3):

Sleeping in the airport should not be a problem. Your situation is not uncommon at all.
The need to spend the night at the airport either for early flights or connecting flights happens.
There is even a website dedicated to this subject with tips regarding the policy of the aiports about people sleeping and the best places to do it.

- http://www.sleepinginairports.net/
- http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/amsterdam.htm