# What to do at the Amsterdam Schiphol Airport during a long transit?

Tags: transit, airports, ams

I have a 12 hours transit at Amsterdam Schiphol airport but I have no visa to exit the airport, and all hotels inside are fully booked. Shops and restaurants are all closed by the time I arrive at the airport. Are there areas to relax and get some sleep? What else is there to do inside?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/38141/22140

Comment: Schiphol's duty free is quite complete, so you will be able to spend some hours checking their stuff. Then, there are some very nice long, comfortable chairs to get some rest.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose by this time OP has already finished his/her layover. For future visitors, here's another suggestion: Visit the Rijksmuseum at Schiphol at no charge! It is open daily from 6:00 – 20:00 and is located between piers E and F.

http://www.iamsterdam.com/en/see-and-do/things-to-do/museums-and-galleries/museums/rijksmuseum-amsterdam-at-schiphol-airport

Also see this list:

https://www.schiphol.nl/en/what-to-do-at-schiphol/relax/after-security/list/

Answer (score 2):

I recently traveled through Schiphol and there are plenty of comfortable seating areas (well padded couches) and lots of power points so you should be very comfortable.

The specific area I had in mind was next to departures gate E08.

There are also automated relax/massage chairs that operate by coin which you can use to time out for a while.

There are 24 hours food and beverage shops, but strangely available in arrivals and not departure.

There are also meditation areas where you can go to relax (although I am not sure if these are open 24 hours).

So you should easily be able to spend 12 hours.

Answer (score 0):

When I had a long layover at Schiphol I found the [airport park](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/facilities/airport-park/) a nice place to kill some time.  In particular you can actually get outside and have some fresh air, if the weather is nice.